# Taking closures with explicit lifetimes as arguments in Rust

Tags: rust, lifetime

The [closures](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/closures.html) section of Rust documentation has this example:

```
fn call_with_ref<'a, F>(some_closure: F) -> i32
    where F: Fn(&'a i32) -> i32
{
    let value = 0;
    some_closure(&value)
}
```

This doesn't compile because, as the docs put it:

> When a function has an explicit lifetime parameter, that lifetime must
>   be at least as long as the entire call to that function. The borrow
>   checker will complain that value doesn't live long enough, because it
>   is only in scope after its declaration inside the function body.

The error message being

```
error: `value` does not live long enough
 --> <anon>:5:19
  |
5 |     some_closure(&value);
  |                   ^^^^^ does not live long enough
...
8 | }
  | - borrowed value only lives until here
```

I am having trouble understanding this. What does it mean that value does not live long enough? From what I understand value lives through the entire call of the function. So, where does the "not living long enough" come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a lifetime appears in the parameter list, that means the caller gets to decide.  The lifetime it chooses can be as long as it likes, and possibly longer than the closure lives for, even `'static`.

Here's a bad example which is prevented by this error:

```
fn call_with_ref<'a, F>(some_closure: F) -> i32
    where F: FnMut(&'a i32) -> i32
{
    let value = 0;
    some_closure(&value)
}

fn main() {
    let mut refstore: Option<&'static i32> = None;

    call_with_ref(|r| {
        refstore = Some(r);
        *r
    });
}
```

If this version of `call_with_ref` were allowed to compile, it would allow storing a dangling reference to the local `value` variable in a variable which lives for longer.

Note I've changed the function to take an `FnMut` closure for simplicity; it would be possible to have the same unsafety using `Fn` and a `RefCell`, but it would have made the example more complicated.

([Playground with "bad" line commented out](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=9dfb6c81ecf323483258860a4743bee8&version=stable&backtrace=1))

The [closures section](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/closures.html) of the book then shows the `for<'a>` syntax, which changes the meaning of the lifetime bound.

Translating to English, the following:

```
fn call_with_ref<'a, F>(some_closure: F) -> i32
     where F: Fn(&'a i32) -> i32
```

means roughly "given a lifetime `'a`, and a callable which takes a reference to an `i32` which is valid for `'a`, I'll return an `i32`".  This means that the lifetime is set *by the caller* of `call_with_ref` and is fixed.

In contrast, the following:

```
fn call_with_ref<F>(some_closure: F) -> i32
     where F: for<'a> Fn(&'a i32) -> i32
```

means "given a callable which can take a reference to an `i32` of any lifetime, I'll return an `i32`".  The difference is that the closure will accept *any* reference lifetime (which outlives the call of the closure).

In the first case, the lifetime is a parameter to `call_with_ref`, so must outlive that call; but in the second case it's a parameter to the closure itself and only needs to outlive the call to the closure.

Comment: But how does this syntax fn call_with_ref<F>(some_closure:F) -> i32
    where F: for<'a> Fn(&'a i32) -> i32 solve the problem?

Comment: I've added a mention of that; hope it helps.

Comment: @ChrisEmerson `for<'a> Fn(&'a i32) -> i32` can also be [written as `Fn(&i32) -> i32`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0387-higher-ranked-trait-bounds.md#implicit-binders-when-using-parentheses-notation-and-in-fn-types).