# How do I pass an async callback containing an argument that is a reference?

Tags: rust, async-await, lifetime

I have a function that requires an asynchronous callback (a request handler); I'm currently trying to accept things that look like this:

```rust
async fn handle_request<'a>(request: Request, body: &'a mut (dyn AsyncRead + 'a)) -> HandlerResponse
```

It had been working up until the addition of the second parameter `body`, which is causing me grief. The function that accepts the parameter looks like this:

```rust
pub async fn process_requests<H, F>(
    mut connection: Box<dyn AsyncConnection>,
    request_handler: &H,
) -> Result<(), DecodeError>
where
    for<'a> H: Fn(crate::Request, &'a mut (dyn AsyncRead + 'a)) -> F + 'a,
    F: Future<Output = HandlerResponse>,
{
```

Part way through this function, we call a helper function:

```
handle_request(&mut connection, request_handler, request)
```

which has a very similar signature; in particular, the signature for `request_handler` is identical. It does some minor pre-processing before invoking `request_handler`. When I attempt to compile this, I get:

```
error[E0310]: the parameter type `H` may not live long enough
    |
106 | pub async fn process_requests<H, F>(
    |                               - help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound `H: 'static`...
...
142 |                     handle_request(&mut connection, request_handler, request)
    |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |
note: ...so that the type `H` will meet its required lifetime bounds
    |
142 |                     handle_request(&mut connection, request_handler, request)
    |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Why do I need this / what do I do about this? Indeed adding `'static` to `H:` in the `where` does seem to silence the error, but is that the right thing to do? Couldn't the type implementing `H` carry a reference, and `'static` would forbid that? I don't necessarily want to do that, but any amount of trying to annotate a lifetime that *isn't* `'static` onto `H` has not worked; e.g., `'a + Fn(...) -> F + 'a` does not work, nor does adding a new generic `'b` lifetime. I'd rather not `'static` something that doesn't need it, but I don't see how to do that.

(I'm also a bit perplexed by the wording of the message — that the *parameter type* — not some argument or variable — doesn't live long enough. How does a type not live long enough?)

I've played with things a bit more, but I still can't get anything that actually compiles. [This playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d5d6c1764f2d11bf9dfe85f152c602eb) shows another one of the more perplexing error messages that I'm running into. I've tried dropping some of the lifetime annotations, and moved the `for<'a>` bit (I'm not sure what the difference is?).

Comment: Since this is a common sense, in case if you missed it, i want to point: `'static` lifetime boundary doesn't mean that it is going remain until the process terminates. `'static` boundary usually used to request ownership of the variable.

Comment: _I'd rather not 'static something that doesn't need it, but I don't see how to do that._ We need an owner since we don't exactly know when `asycn fn` will be executed. Simply we can't be sure that the borrowed argument will live on that moment. It needs to be `static` or `owned` or `unmovable`(refering `Pin`s in here, which i have superficial knowledge about it)

Comment: While the explanation in your second comment is correct, I disagree with your first statement _`'static` boundary usually used to request ownership of the variable_. A `'static` lifetime bound means the borrow has `'static` lifetime, meaning the entire duration of the program. It is still a borrow though.

Comment: Do reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42648637/8511998) address your issue?

Comment: @L.Riemer It may not cover the whole concept but i don't think it is wrong, It basically ensures that `H` can be a argument type as `String` not a `&String`.(assuming `String` has implemented `Fn`). If you really need a static borrow you need to define your parameter like : `&'static H`

Comment: It is wrong in that transferring ownership includes giving up ownership in one scope and acquiring it in an other. With `&'static` you don't do that. Most times, such values are binary-included globals, which you can't possibly own (or closures, which have this lifetime by birthright). That's a strict difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A callback argument passed as reference does not work with HRTB constraints when the callback is marked with the `async` keyword.

The signature using `async/await`:

```
async fn handle_request<'a>(request: Request, body: &'a mut (dyn AsyncRead + 'a)) -> HandlerResponse
```

Is equivalent to:

```
fn handle_request<'a>(request: Request, body: &'a mut (dyn AsyncRead + 'a)) -> Future<Output=HandlerResponse> + 'a
```

This implies that input lifetimes of an async function are captured in the 
future returned by the async function.

See the paragraph "Lifetime capture in the anonymous future" of [RFC 2394](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2394-async_await.md#lifetime-capture-in-the-anonymous-future).

Declaring the function that accepts the parameter as:

```
pub async fn process_requests<H, F>(
    mut connection: Box<dyn AsyncConnection>,
    request_handler: &H,
) -> Result<(), DecodeError>
where
    for<'a> H: Fn(crate::Request, &'a mut (dyn AsyncRead + 'a)) -> F + 'a,
    F: Future<Output = HandlerResponse>,
{
```

Give a compilation error because the HRTB requirement:

```
for<'a> H: Fn(crate::Request, &'a mut (dyn AsyncRead + 'a)) -> F + 'a
```

"unlink" the lifetime bound from the caller and produce the compilation error
`expected bound lifetime parameter 'a, found concrete lifetime`

for more details about HRTB see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35592750/how-does-for-syntax-differ-from-a-regular-lifetime-bound/35595491#35595491).

To make it works you have to write:

```
pub async fn process_requests<'a, H, F>(
    mut connection: Box<dyn AsyncConnection>,
    request_handler: &H,
) -> Result<(), DecodeError>
where
    H: Fn(crate::Request, &'a mut (dyn AsyncRead + 'a)) -> F + 'a,
    F: Future<Output = HandlerResponse>,
{
```

But this get you to another problem:

```
`body` does not live long enough
```

because the local body struct does not outlive `request_handler`:

```
async fn handle_request<'a, H, F>(
    request_handler: &H,
    request: Request,
) -> io::Result<()>
where
    H: Fn(Request, &'a mut (dyn AsyncRead + 'a)) -> F,
    F: Future<Output = String>,
{
    let mut body = Body {};
    request_handler(request, &mut body);
    unimplemented!();
}
```

If feasible
one possible solution could be to use Boxed trait objects and get rid off HTRB constraints.

Comment: I'm aware that input lifetimes to `async fn`s end up "on" the `impl Future`; I mostly follow your answer. <s>But you say, "this gets you to another problem" "`body` does not live long enough" — and that `body` must outlive `request_handler` — why must it outlive `request_handler`? I would only expect it to need to outlive the future that `request_handler` returns, no?</s> Oh, b/c you've removed the HRTB. Yes, w/o the HRTB, I agree, `body` does not live long enough / I agree w/ the tail end of your post. That was what pushed me to HRTB; but why does it not work w/ the HRTB?

Comment: As for your recommendation to `Box` trait objects… would you mean the `Fn` or the `AsyncRead`, or both? The `Fn` would probably be considerably simpler if `Box`ed, and I think I'll do that. The `AsyncRead` has a reference to something `handle_request` needs, unfortunately, _and_ that function makes use of it after the callback (`request_handler`).

Comment: It does not work with HRTB because the arg of`process_requests(&handler)` depends
on an `AsyncRead` reference that depends on a bound lifetime `'b`: `async fn handler<'b>(..., body: &'b mut (dyn AsyncRead + 'b))` 

But in your `process_request` you are declaring an HRTB constraint `for<'a>Fn(crate::Request, &'a mut (dyn AsyncRead + 'a))`
that is incompatible with the "single" bounded lifetime requirement stated with the def of `handler`.

Comment: I was generic about the Boxed trait suggestion because it really depends on your requirements.

Comment: I'm still not following the reasoning on why the HRTB example doesn't work. You call it a "bound lifetime", but in what way (particularly at the site of the error, which is  is it "bound"? Is it not "bound" when I finally pass in a `&dyn AsyncRead`, at which point the lifetime is "bound" to that of the concrete `AsyncRead` that I am passing in?

Will it not work as written, or at all? If not at all, how it not a bug in the language that I can't pass this function as a generic argument?

Comment: See [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9d3f4135acd47371168d1e24cc27227e), perhaps it can help.

Comment: I eventually moved this to a trait that had a member `fn`; after I did that, I realized the member fn needed to be async, and so then I ran into async-trait and http://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2019/10/26/async-fn-in-traits-are-hard/ ; I *think* perhaps that the problems outlined there are essentially what I'm running into here? At any rate, dtolnay's async-trait worked out, and I think the core advice here — get rid of the need for HTRB — was pretty close to what I needed.